# Strings as key in Hashmap

Tags: java, string, hashmap

I'm newbie with Java
Is it possible to convert a String, or a String[] as the keys of an Hashmap?
I mean:

```
String keysToConvert = "key1,key2,key3";
```

into

```
HashMap<String, Double> hashmap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
[apply in some way the keys of the string]
hashmap.get("key2");
```

I know that `hashmap.get("key2");`has no value in this moment. I just would know if there is a way to load the keys in an HashMap.

Comment: If you have String[], you can add them using a for-each loop.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Try to read about `String#split` method.

Comment: your need is not clear what do you mean by " I just would know if there is a way to load the keys in an HashMap" what exactly is not clear to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have String[], you can add them using a for-each loop:

```
String[] keys = {"key1", "key2", "key3"};
HashMap<String, Double> hashmap = new HashMap<String, Double>();

for (String key : keys) {
    hashmap.put(key, null);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
hashmap.put("key2", 1.0d);
System.out.println(hashmap.get("key2")); // prints 1.0
```

This is the basic usage of a Map